Page-Break issue when converting html to pdf using jspdf
i am building a resumetemplate using react and jspdf for this i have build a template and sending it to the jspdf for download but the problem is when i added extra content for example if i add a table the table get cut in half between 2 pages that looks messy and does not deliver the actual page formatting
doc.html(reportTemplateRef.current, {
            x:  marginLeft,
            y: marginTop,
            html2canvas: {
                scale: scale,
            },
            callback: () => {
                
                const contentHeight = height * scale;
                const pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight()- marginTop - marginBottom;
                if (contentHeight > pageHeight) {
              
                    doc.setPage(doc.getNumberOfPages()); 
                    doc.html(reportTemplateRef.current, {
                        x: marginLeft,
                        y: paddingTop ,
                        html2canvas: {
                            scale: scale,
                        },
                    });
                }
                console.log(doc.getNumberOfPages())
                
                doc.save('document.pdf');
            },
        });

i have tried to add gap between pages or add margin from top but only the first page got margin
i want that each page have a specific space between content and the page and if some div cannot come to one page fully then it should just shift to the next page

can you suggest some other way by which my table dont get cut between pages
